# Rspec - Mock the model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have following methods,

Model/Summary.rb

```
def show_summary
    device_lastest_reading = lastest_reading
  end
```

Model/Reading.rb

```
def lastest_reading
    select_readings(start_date, last_date)
  end
```

The `lastest_reading` method get the values from a hardware. I have created a `DummyReading.rb` for RSPEC and placed the `lastest_reading` method as like below,

DummyReading.rb

```
def lastest_reading
    {
      :a=>13,
      :b=>"7666",
      :c=>6729690,
    }
  end
```

here is what i tried,

```
it "should return summary data" do
        allow(DummyReading.lastest_reading).to receive(Model.show_summary).and_return({})
      end
```

I an getting error "`undefined method`to_sym' for {}:Hash`"

In rspec how to mock/stub this device_lastest_reading variable.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand how you think this code will even run. You're defining `latest_reading` in Reading but your calling it in Summary as if it where an instance method of that class. Can you clarify this by writing actual classes as a minimal RUNNABLE example instead? And why is the file extension `.cs` and not `rb`? You also don't need to create a separate class just for your tests. Use an [instance double](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/verifying-doubles/using-an-instance-double) instead to mock the collaborator.

Comment: @max During RSPEC execution in show_summary method, i need to get values from DummyReading.rb -> lastest_reading method rather than Model/Reading.rb -> lastest_reading method. Is their any way i can do this.

Comment: Can you please edit the question as requested so that the code is actually understandable/runnable? Repeating the same question again does not help. I'm not daft. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is that `Model.show_summary` will give an no method error since its a instance and not a class method. And even if it did it would error out on `lastest_reading` as that method is defined in a completely different class. Mocking is really irrelevant if you don't even get the basics of OOP.

Answer (score -1):

As @max mentioned, you should do proper homework before asking. First understand the difference between mocking and stubbing and how it works with [rspec](http://rubyblog.pro/2017/10/rspec-difference-between-mocks-and-stubs).

For quick assistance, following should work.

```
it "should return summary data" do
  allow_any_instance_of(Reading).to receive(:latest_reading).and_return(DummyReading.new.latest_reading)
end
```

Though, `allow_any_instance_of` is not recommended. Checkout [style guide](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/1.7.0/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/AnyInstance).